# Characterizing properties of the given set (regression coefficient). Is it convex? Does it have holes? Is it compact?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, convex-analysis, compactness, connectedness

The set is defined as:

$\mathbb{S} = \{\frac{\sum_{i=1}^Nx_iy_i}{\sum_{i=1}^Nx_i^2} |x_i \in [\underline{x}_i,\overline{x}_i] \hspace{0.1cm} \text{for all $i$, and }\overline{x}_i, \underline{x}_i, y_i \in \mathbb{R}^1, \sum_{i=1}^N x_i^2 \neq 0  \}$.

I am interested in characterizing the properties of this set. I am thinking of this like a regression. The function defining the set is the formula of the regression coefficient. I want to know what this set looks like for a fixed $y_i$ that I get from the data but where my $x_i$ are interval censored but my interval bounds i.e. $\underline{x}_i$ and $\overline{x}_i$ are fixed. In other words I am thinking of this set as conditional on the values of $y_i, \underline{x}_i, \overline{x}_i$ and so these numbers cannot be varied. Only the $x_i$ can vary. In particular, I want to know if this set is convex, does it have holes (is it simply connected or like a torus), is it compact? In light of John Hughes answer, I think I am looking for ranges of $\underline{x}_i$ $\overline{x}_i$ and $y_i$, where these properties will hold true or not (unless they always hold true).

I think it should be okay to consider the case where N=2 because the results should generalize. Couple of observations that I made:

1) If $0\in [\underline{x}_i,\overline{x}_i] \hspace{0.1cm} \text{for all $i$}$, then the set is not defined. Hence the added condition, suggested by one of the responses, that $\sum_{i=1}^N x_i^2 \neq 0$.

2) For the N=2 case, the gradient is given by the following:

$$[\frac{(-y_1)x_1^2 - (2x_2y_2)x_1 - x_2^2y_1}{(x_1^2+x_2^2)^2}, \frac{(-y_2)x_2^2 - (2x_1y_1)x_2 - x_1^2y_2}{(x_1^2+x_2^2)^2}]$$

This shows that the numerator is essentially a quadratic. If I want to solve for a local optima, fixing $x_{-i}$, I can solve a quadratic in $x_i$ to get the maximum or minimum (a constrained problem because of the bounds).

Questions:

1) **Is this set convex**? My hunch is that it is not. I tried the following:

We know that $\frac{\underline{x}_1y_1+\underline{x}_2y_2}{\underline{x}_1^2+\underline{x}_2^2} \in \mathbb{S}$ and $\frac{\overline{x}_1y_1+\overline{x}_2y_2}{\overline{x}_1^2+\overline{x}_2^2} \in \mathbb{S}$. Now consider the weighted sum of these two, where each of them get a weight of 0.5. We get the following expression:
$$0.5 \times \frac{(\overline{x}_1^2 \underline{x}_1 + \overline{x}_2^2 \underline{x}_1)y_1 + (\overline{x}_1^2 \underline{x}_2 + \overline{x}_2^2 \underline{x}_2)y_2}{(\overline{x}_1^2 \underline{x}_1 + \overline{x}_2^2 \underline{x}_1)\underline{x}_1 + (\overline{x}_1^2 \underline{x}_2 + \overline{x}_2^2 \underline{x}_2)\underline{x}_2}$$
I am not sure how to show that this does not lie inside $\mathbb{S}$.

2) **Is it correct that otherwise the set is compact**? My intuition is that its bounded and closed, if $0$ is not in both intervals, so it must be compact in this case.

3)**I am not sure how to show that this set does not contain holes (like torus) of the nature shown in this picture on wikipedia**:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simply_connected_space#/media/File:Runge_theorem.svg

My intuition is that these are not present. The only problematic case is when $0$ is in both intervals but if this is not true then these holes shouldn't be there.

How do I show that this set is simply connected? Is this the same as connected? Except for the case where the $0$ is in both intervals, plots of this function look somewhat spiky but connected in the sense that the plots don't really show holes. Though I don't know if this rules out the case shown in wikipedia.

Comment: The set is not well-defined if $0$ is in all the intervals, for in that case, the denominator sum can be zero, and its reciprocal is undefined.

Comment: @JohnHughes I see. Yes. I am fine with the special case where 0 is not in both intervals. Should I edit the entire question?

Comment: I think I thought that it would become unbounded if denominator can take value 0. This is wrong right? It is undefined.

Comment: It might be that you want to add $\sum_{i=1}^N x_i^2 \ne 0$ as a condition on the right-hand side of your set-construction formula for $S$.

Comment: NB: " In other words I am thinking of this set as conditional on the values of ,⎯⎯,⎯⎯⎯ and so these numbers cannot be varied." and "for all , and ⎯⎯⎯,⎯⎯,∈ℝ1" are not consistent (or at the very least, not clear).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. If $0$ is in all the intervals, then the set is not well-defined, so I'll ignore that case.
2. If $0$ is not in all the intervals, then there is some interval --- we might as well make it the first --- containing some number $s$ other than $0$. Now we can pick $x_1 = s$ and pick $x_i = \overline{x_i}$ for $i = 2, 3, \ldots$. Pick $y_i = 0 $ for $x_i = 2, 3, \ldots$ as well. Then the sum becomes
   $$
   \frac{s_1y_1}{s_1^2} = \frac{1}{s_1} y_1
   $$
   Because $k = 1/s_1 \ne 0$, these products $ky_1$ range over all real numbers, so the set $S$ contains all of $\Bbb R$ -- it's connected, noncompact, convex, has no holes. I think that's the whole story.

Comment: I see. Would it be possible for you to answer this for a given set of $y_i$, where we cannot pick the $y_i$? I am thinking of this from a regression perspective where the formula is the regression coefficient. I have the all the $y_i$ but my $x_i$ are interval censored in the data.

Comment: Is it infeasible to think of this from $y_i$ being some fixed numbers? As in, would the properties vary wildly for some $y_i$ versus the other? Further, I am confused by a part of your answer. Why does $ky_1$ range over all real numbers, when $s_1$ is bounded? Are you using that we can set $y_1$ to infinity?

Comment: I added a few more remarks in the first para of my question. May be those help a bit. I see why I was unclear at first.

Comment: These are totally different questions from the one you asked. You should not alter the question, but rather should ask a new one that says what you mean. But now that you've shown you're willing to waste my time by not phrasing your question carefully, I'm done. Maybe someone else will be fool enough ...

Comment: I am sorry you feel that way and apologize if your time was wasted. It was not intentional. The fact that you say that "maybe someone else will be fool enough..." suggests that you think it was intentional. My mistake was that the definition of the set didn't include the word fixed, though I also didn't say for all $y_i$. Its a mistake but not egregious enough to warrant comments that I am purposefully wasting time, which is what your comment suggests. Again, for which I apologize.

Comment: I've spent a lot of time answering questions where my answer ends up showing a lot more effort than the questioner's phrasing, which changes after the fact. Now I'm old and jaded and see that everywhere.

Comment: I understand. It's just that I dont have a teacher and I self-learn and so am not bouncing ideas off another person . Sometimes the write up to me seems clear because I have been thinking of the problem but it isnt to others. It was not intentional. Hope you have a nice day.